# HttpClient is sending NULL in web Api in mvc5

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

HttpClient is sending null values to controller while post and my code is here please help me
....................

```
using (HttpClient client=new HttpClient())
                    {


                            var parameters = ConvertToDictionary(tc);

                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:9797/");

                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tc);
                        var data = new StringContent(content: json,encoding: Encoding.UTF8,mediaType: "application/json");
                        var response = client.PostAsync(api_url, data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        var k = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Api>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @ insted of $ in client.BaseAddress. And check if tc object is not null.
I used Your code like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (HttpClient client=new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:61737/api/presidents");

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { name = "name", value = "value" });
            var data = new StringContent(content: json,encoding: Encoding.UTF8,mediaType: "application/json");
            var response = client.PostAsync(@"http://localhost:61737/api/presidents/post", data).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var k = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
        }
    }
}
```

And controller looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/presidents")]
public class PresidentsController : ApiController
{
    public class oooo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    [Route("post")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(oooo o)
    {
        return Ok(o);
    }
}
```

and everything is working.